# jQuery ajax issue(succes data not correct)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a small ajax contact form and i am testing it with a basic php file(learning the whole jQuery ajax thing), but for some reason it doesn't works.

Even if the data is correct it stil gives me the error code(if data = ok doent work).

here's the basic jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#contactform").submit(function(){

        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: obj.attr('method'),
            url: obj.attr('action'),
            data: str,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){  

                $('.acf-wrap').ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){  

                    if(data == 'OK'){
                        msg = 'success';
                    }else{
                        msg = data;

                    }

                    //display msg
                    $(this).html(msg);

                });

            }       
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

test php file

```
if(1 == 1){
    echo 'OK';
}else{
    echo 'error!!!';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is probably a JSON string. JSON.parse the data and access the "d" property...

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
if(parsed.d == 'OK'){
    alert('works');
}
```

Actually wrote this answer on my phone... Might not be right. Couldn't test it... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP will never echo 'OK', because 1 will never equal 2. At least not in the universe I'm from.

```
if(1 ==2){
```

How can that ever be true? Either it won't, or a philosopher will need to weigh in.

Comment: sorry about that,but i did tested it with a true value. Also the error message will put out text plus some php code, so thats not good to

Comment: If you're seeing `<?`, `<?php`, etc. in the browser, then you need to move the PHP to a web server. PHP is not like HTML that you can simply run from your desktop -- it's actually executed by a web server so it has to be there to work properly.

Comment: damm you are right, i tested it with wamp, but that didnt work, uploaded it to a test site and it works.......stupid me :P thanks!!